# Hardware for Operating System development

Tags: microcontroller, cpu, microprocessor

I am heavily interested in Operating System theory and design and have decided I would like to play with developing an OS. I have a background in x86 assembly and have looked into ARM also. I would like a development board to develop the OS for. Has anyone had experience with OS development and/or can suggest some hardware to use?

One board I am considering is the [LPC1769 LPCXpresso board](http://www.lpctools.com/lpc1768.lpcxpresso.aspx).

I am aware I could use a VM, but I would like to use actual hardware.

Comment: Few questions: How lowlevel do you want to start? Do you plan to write your on BIOS? Did you already study Minix?

Comment: Next question: how high-end do you want to finish? Make your own USB stack, TCP/IP, file systems, GUI, etc?

Comment: BIOS development isn't in the immediate future, but if the option was there it would be great. As for the far end, I will be attempting to write USB & TCP/IP stacks, GUI, etc.

Comment: This question is polling for any system that might be good for an OS, any system could be used for making an OS almost and would be a good fit.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use a normal PC.  These come with x86 processors and all the other hardware and are exactly the kind of platforms that benefit from operating systems.  Even a old junker PC would be fine for this.  You develop on a regular PC running a real operating system and test on the klunker.  The other advantage to this is that it's free.  Surely you have some old PC or motherboard sitting around in some dusty corner, or know someone who does that has gotten around to tossing it out yet.

Comment: His initial idea to go for an ARM is sensible. If I wanted to write an experimental OS, I wouldn't touch x86 with a bargepole. x86 not a nice environment to start low level programming in. You'd want something without segmenation that has good cross-compiler support.

Comment: @posipiet, he said she had x86 experience.

Comment: A normal PC was my original idea also, I thought I would firstly see if anyone had any other suggestions.

Answer (score 2):

What are you after? A complete PC OS, or rather an RTOS (Real Time Operating System)? If you are going to write your own PC OS , I would suggest an old PC like Olin said.

Coincidently I am currently trying to (just for fun) write my own RTOS on a small PIC24FJ32GA002 (had it lying around, easy to work and test with). This is a simple 28-pin 16MIPS 16-bit controller, but does the job in my case. I currently got a task kernel working so I can switch tasks, use delays handled by the RTOS etc. Now moving on to more abstract features with memory and peripheral communication (handled by the RTOS).

I don't think you need a monster microcontroller to run any RTOS. The task kernal only consumes 500~600 instructions and about 300~400 bytes of RAM for 2(+1idle) tasks. Even this low memory device has 10.5k instructions and 8KB of RAM, so I am only using about 5% now.

For an RTOS its very important that the CPU supports some kind of easy stack changing, so you can change the application context fast. For example, I know some of the older PICs (like a PIC16 or a PIC18 device) have got hardware based stacks. On the PIC24 I am storing the context (pushing CPU registers onto the stack), changing the stack pointer (to the stack of another task) and resuming the context (popping CPU registers from the stack).

The ARM chips doesn't have a hardware based stack, so they are good to go. Note that the LPCXpresso board comes with it's own compiler and development environment. This means you **must** use the code_red compiler and environment for the onboard debugger.  The debugger doesn't work with another environment, because the software for the debugger is loaded by their own IDE. The free compiler version of the compiler also has a 128KB code restriction. This is amount of code that can be debugged, I believe. 128KB is plenty for a small RTOS to start with.

You can always get your own JLINK or JTAG programmer, but you would have to wire the SW or JTAG port to the LPC1769 board. Other than that, the LPC1769 has plenty of resources and peripherals to start going. I don't know from my experience how good the debugging tools is on the LPCxpresso when you're debugging really low-end stuff (like task switching). On the PIC24 I had to second-guess what is going on, MPLAB didn't properly capture hang-ups.. Nevertheless it's still possible. For ARM there also plenty of RTOS and resources out there to take a peek at.